# Approval status changed to waiting for approval after some changes in existing list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am new to SP. Please help me to find the below solution.

Senario-1: A user raised a request in sharepoint list. Request went for respective reporting manager approval. Due to incomplete information, Approver rejected the  request. Reject request went back to user with the approver comment "Incomplete information". User changed the requested information details which was suggested by approver. **"But after after doing the changes in sharepoint list. It is not going to approver for approval.Please help me on this. How it will again trigger a approval email to the approver."**

Comment: are you using SharePoint designer workflow ?

Comment: No Karthik, i am using MS PowerAutomate.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this idea, i am not sure exactly about it. Create a SharePoint list column Status and set the status "Waiting" by default and after approval of manager change it to "Approved". And set timeout at every 1 minute and check the condition in MS Power Automate that if(Status == "Waiting") then flow will trigger at every 1 minute.